# How to use outside column in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have following query-

```
select * from 
Table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,
(select idCol from table3) t3
```

My question is - Can I use table t2 inside subquery?

like this

```
select * from 
Table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,
(select idCol, t2.nameCol from table3) t3
```

Obviously this gives error `invalid identifier t2.nameCol`

But if I write as follows, it give unnecessaru extra rows

```
select * from 
Table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,
(select idCol,  t2.nameCol from table3, table2 t2) t3
```

any other way to do this?

**EDIT**

Basically what I am trying to achieve is following

```
select * from 
Table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,
(select 
    case
    when t2.nameCol = 'ABC'  then 'ABC'
    else idCol
    end idCol from table3) t3
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You're already cross joining t1, t2 and the subquery, why do you need t2's columns inside the subquery too?

Comment: @Mureinik Please see my edits

Comment: This still doesn't make too much sense to me. Could you please post your table structures, some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: you can use t2 in a where clause, such as `select * from 
Table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,
(select idCol from table3 where t3name = t2.nameCol) t3` since t2 is already in the outer statement. you cannot list is as a field in the select part, since it is not in the from part of the inner clause.

Comment: It looks like you want a subquery in your SELECT clause rather than in your FROM clause. Well, it's hard to tell with such a mutilated query (including an out-dated join syntax that was used in the 1980s, but shouldn't be used today).

Comment: The actual table structure is big and this is just a sample structure. What I want to achieve is while getting idCol from T3, if nameCol of t2 is 'ABC' just print 'ABC' else idCol of T3.

Answer (score 0):

To join a table only when certain criteria is met is called an outer join. Here is how:

```
select *
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on <join criteria here>
left outer join table3 t3 on t2.namecol <> 'ABC' and <join criteria here>;
```

It may suffice in your case, however, to move the subquery to your SELECT clause:

```
select 
  t1.*, 
  t2.*, 
  case when t2.namecol = 'ABC' then 
    'ABC' 
  else 
    (select idcol from table3 t3 where <join criteria here>) 
  end
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on <join criteria here>;
```

Comment: The only problem would be in case the query returns multiple results.

Comment: @Radu Gheorghiu: You are right. We know too little of the actual query and the tables, so I wrote "it  *may* suffice..." in order to show a possible alternative.

Comment: Is this the only possible way? As I really dont want to alter the actual query

Comment: You really provided much too little information for us to answer this. You want to change your query without changing it? Er, well, ... :-| If everything is already working and you only want to replace t3.idcol with 'ABC' in your results, then maybe to replace `idcol` with `case when t2.namecol = 'ABC' then 'ABC' else idcol end` in your *SELECT* clause already solves your problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `case when t2.namecol = 'ABC' then 'ABC' else idcol end` gives error 'Invalid identifier

Comment: Sorry, you will have to check this out yourself. You should be able to read your query and understand such error message when you want to change it. If not, you should ask someone who can, in order to avoid introducing any flaws.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.  I am sure you have some kind of join between t1 and t2. IN such case, you can add same at the end of the statement.

```
SELECT t1.*,
   t2.*,
   ( SELECT CASE 
            WHERE t2.nameco1 = 'ABC' THEN 'ABC'
             ELSE idcol
             END idcol
     FROM   table3) idcol
FROM   table1 t1,
       table2 t2
```